# capture and save image in open CV2.4.9 & visual 2013

Tags: opencv

I try below code to capture a single image using camera with openCV and save it.I run this code step over and the image saved(with F10 button) but when i run it in debug mode it show the error which is typed in the code,please tell me the solution and the reason that this happening;

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
   // Capture the Image from the webcam
    VideoCapture cap(0);

   // Get the frame
   Mat save_img; 
   while (1)
  {

        cap >> save_img;

        time_t start_time, cur_time;

        time(&start_time);
      do
      {
            time(&cur_time);
      } while ((cur_time - start_time) < 5);


       if (save_img.empty())
      {
            std::cerr << "Something is wrong with the webcam, could not get frame." << std::endl;
      }
      // Save the frame into a file
      imwrite("test.jpg", save_img);
      char c = cvWaitKey(30);
      if (c == 27) break;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

here

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more? What error are you seeing?

Comment: please, we need to see your code and the exact error msg.